# Как реализовать сервисы для контроллера как в Symfony, но с нуля?

Tags: php, symfony

Допустим, есть некая mvc система, где action'ы лежат в классах контроллера. И я хочу реализовать передачу каких-то классов из определенного каталога напрямую в метод, например:

```
public function index(Service $service)
{
 return $this->render($service);
}
```

$service - это объект класса, расположенного в определенном месте (директория Lib, допустим).

Такое можно делать в Symfony, но я не особо понимаю как можно это сделать своими руками с нуля.

Изначально не известно что будет подано в метод, класс Service или какой-то ещё (возможно несколько). При этом объекты не должны создаваться заранее.

Примерный результат:

```
public function deleteUser(Response $response, Logger $logger, UserRepository $userRepository)
{
.....
$id = $userRepository->getIds()[0];

$userRepository->deleteUser($id);
.....
return $response->send('user '.$id.' deleted');
}
```

Было бы круто увидеть простой пример реализации или паттерн описывающий такой функционал.

Comment: Что значит "Изначально не известно что будет подано в метод, класс Service или какой-то ещё (возможно несколько)"? Это какая-то бессмыслица. Сервисы не передаются в метод, сервис передаётся в конструктор

Comment: @Ипатьев конструктор - тот же метод, поэтому вполне себе можно и в другой метод передавать сервисы, симфони так позволяет делать.

Comment: А ключевые слова для автора это __Dependency Injection__.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю ознакомиться с понятием [Dependency Injection](https://habr.com/ru/post/350068/) [(внедрение зависимостей)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Но, в общих словах, DI это некий контейнер зависимостей, который вы в своем приложении собираете сами, Symfony от 3-ей версии действительно довольно сахарно реализует внедрение зависимостей.

Представим, что у нас имеется 3 типа классов:

1. Классы, у которых сигнатура метода конструктора не определена - вы можете создавать на лету, т.е. при разборе определенного маршрута в ядре вашего приложения, вам нужно проверить (чтобы это проверить, стоить прочитать про [рефлексию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php)), что конструктор не имеет параметров и проинтанцировать  класс зависимости и отдать его как аргумент в целевой.
2. Классы, у которых имеются дефолтные значения в сигнатуре метода конструктора, аналогично, вы можете попробовать сделать инстанс на основе этих, дефолтных значений (ReflectionAPI предоставляет вам эту возможность).
3. Классы, у которых в сигнатуре конструктора параметры, представлены другими классами, у которых аналогично другие классы в зависимостях. Тут все сложнее, вы можете парсить в соответствии с PSR-4 директории, искать классы с соответствующим названием и от них искать их зависимости, пытаться зарезолвить их дойдя до базовых классов и используя пункты 1 и 2 пройти всю иерархию снизу вверх.

P.S. Symfony делает примерно что-то подобное.